# ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary on a dll in a zipped directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, ctypes

I call upon the might of StackOverflow, that I might deploy this software!

This software uses ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary to load a dll. When deployed (mangled by py2exe) the dll is tucked away in a zip that contains a directory structure. The dll is a couple of levels deep in this structure. (I'm not sure if that's a relevant detail.) LoadLibrary fails because it cannot find the dll because the path to it is `...\site.zip\app\dll32\lfx.dll`.

I can't find anything for this on SO or Google. I'm considering doing a try-except on the LoadLibrary call and, in the except block, checking whether the given path refers to a zipped location, unzipping, and trying again.

Is there a more graceful way to load a dll from a zip?

Comment: Why is the *.dll* in a *.zip*? Isn't *.py* the script that calls it also in that *.zip*? You' need to provide more details. If the whole thing works outside the *Py2Exe* context, it should work from within it.

Comment: In this project, dependencies are managed, partly, by separating the project into packages. The main package depends on another package that wraps the _.dll_. The dependency package uses a relative path based on `__file__` to locate and load the _.dll_. Using the --bundle 2 option on py2exe, the dependency package - and therefore the _.dll_ - ends up in a _.zip_ file. So the relative path ends up being of the form mentioned above, which fails to load with `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()`.

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

In order to load a *.dll*, *CTypes* uses:

- *Nix*: [[man7]: DLOPEN(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)
- *Win*: [[MS.Docs]: LoadLibraryW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw)

Both require a **valid file name that exists on the *FS*** (or *NULL*, but that's irrelevant here). The file name you provide doesn't meet the criteria, as the *FS* doesn't automatically handle *.zip* (or other) files when present in a path. 
So the *.dll* needs to be unpacked before loading it. There are a number of ways to do this, here's one that uses a *Context Manager* ([[Python 3.Docs]: Data model - With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers)) or *CM*.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct
import zipfile as zf
import os


if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win":
    from ctypes import wintypes as wt
    unload_lib = ct.WinDLL("kernel32.dll").FreeLibrary
    unload_lib.argtypes = [wt.HMODULE]
    unload_lib.restype = wt.BOOL
else:
    unload_lib = ct.CDLL(None).dlclose
    unload_lib.argtypes = [ct.c_void_p]
    unload_lib.restype = ct.c_int


class ZippedDll():
    def __init__(self, zip_file_name, member_file_name, loader=ct.CDLL, extract_path=None, suppress_exceptions=False):
        self.zip_file_name = zip_file_name
        self.member_file_name = member_file_name
        self.loader = loader
        self.extract_path = extract_path
        self.suppress_exceptions = suppress_exceptions
        self.dll_path = None
        self.dll = None


    def __enter__(self):
        self.dll_path = os.path.join(self.extract_path, self.member_file_name) if self.extract_path else self.member_file_name
        if os.path.exists(self.dll_path):
            self.dll_path = None
            raise OSError("Target file already exists")
        with zf.ZipFile(self.zip_file_name) as zip_file:
            zip_file.extract(self.member_file_name, path=self.extract_path if self.extract_path else None)
        try:
            self.dll = self.loader(self.dll_path)
        except OSError:
            if not self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
                raise
        return self.dll


    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.dll:
            unload_lib(self.dll._handle)
            self.dll = None
        if self.dll_path and os.path.isfile(self.dll_path):
            os.unlink(self.dll_path)
            self.dll_path = None
        return self.suppress_exceptions


def main(*argv):
    with ZippedDll("arch.zip", "dir00/dll00.dll", loader=ct.WinDLL) as dll:
        print(dll._name, dll.dll00Func00)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- For this example, I used an archive *arch.zip* with the following structure

  - *dir00/*

    - *dll00.dll* (from another *SO* answer) exporting a function (*dll00Func00*)
- The *CM* unpacks the *.dll*, loads it, and at the end (when exiting *with*) cleans things up (except for the intermediary directories)
- More error handling can be added
- I didn't test the *Nix* part

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060348430>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> dir00/dll00.dll <_FuncPtr object at 0x000002A045422E18>
>
> Done.
> ```